# Build fail on cordova blank project VS 2013

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013

I installed Apache Cordova Tools for VS 2013 and after creating a new blank aplication is giving the following error:
[image]

I'm building Device Debug Android.
And i have Android SDK Tools 19.1 installed.

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible Answers:

1. use 'clear cordova cache' in tools, options, tools For apache cordova.  then, rebuild your Project but make sure you have an internet connection when you rebuild.
2. try to use a Windows user name that do not contain SPACE before installation of tools for apache cordova.
3. try to use a project location and project name that do not contain space.

I assume you are using Visual Studio 2013 Community Update 4 with Tools For Apache Cordova Ctp3.1, if not, upgrade to this version.

btw, according to microsoft, cordova in vs 2013 is going to be deprecated, since you are just started, why not download and install vs 2015 Community rc, it solves a few problems in 2013 and it can co-exist with 2013.

Comment: Hey Kenneth, thx for asnwer. I maked the clear cach and i got a error list now,its better then nothing. And i'm goting this: http://imgur.com/G8sUIye
I also showing my node and npm, i check for this way on error and i dont have /lib. Answer u i cant use VS 2015. And my VS 2013 is Ultimate.

Comment: did you install node.js manually?  vs cordova only support node.js 0.10.x, it has problem with note 0.12.x

Comment: Yes i have installed manually, when install tools for cordova, also install node.js ? If i remove node.js and reinstall cordova for VS, can fix that?

Answer (score 0):

If you install Tools For apache cordova, node.js will be installed. I tried upgrade node.js from 0.10 to 0.12, then some problems appears, so I uninstall note and cordova, and reinstall cordova to fix it.

Comment: sorry, it should be a comment, I press the wrong button in my mobile phone.  Btw, if you use vs cordova, there are few things that may make your development easier, e.g. use only one index.html file in the whole app.  i.e. don't create Another html file.